# Google Chrome Issue

Tags: google-chrome, browser

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Version, While opening the Google chrome >= 72 system gets hang. But Google chrome 70 or 71 Works well

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Did you try reinstalling it from scratch? Uninstall Google Chrome then look for the configuration folder in `/home/.config` folder and delete Google Chrome folder. This will delete your profile *completely*. After that install the newest stable version of Chrome.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I downloaded from the Google-chrome website and Installed by the method of #dpkg -i google*.deb. And now I will try, what you say!

Comment: uninstall Chrome and never use it, install chromium or firefox

Comment: @JoKeR, I have tried.but, Issue still remains!

Comment: did you try to install Chromium `sudo apt install chromium` and check? you won't see a big difference between them.

Comment: Yes. I did that. Chromium works well. Google-chrome is the problem